# Do we need Separate Storyboards for all iPhone/iPad Devices?

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

I am trying to find answer, That Since we have iPhone 4, 5 ,6, 6 plus (I heard some rumors about iPhone 6 mini too) do we need Different Storyboards?

Earlier I use to make the Applications using XIB files only. Taking one XIB for iPhone 4 and 5 and using autoresizing to make them Compatible for both devices. If I had to make the same application for iPad also, I had to take the different XIB.

After Xcode 6.1 release I started using the StoryBoards and auto-layout, Size Classes. I made an app that was for all iPhones and iPad. I used a single Storyboard for iPhone and iPad and got success. But doing this was very time consuming.

From now on Should I make different Storyboards? **Like one for iPhone  4 and 5, another one for iPhone 6 and 6 plus?** Because Some time the UI's are too complex that using auto-layout or auto-resizing on the same Storyboard for all devices just destroy the beauty of the UI.

Please Suggest. And I have gone through some Stack answers that are not much Convincing.

Comment: Size class are enough make changes for iPhones (4, 5, 6). Using AutoLayout you can manage view changes. What I suggest is to make different Storyboards for iPhone and iPad is better option in your case.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, different storyboards for iPhone/iPad is necessary only if you gonna provide large different layout for them.

The basic rule is how many views have different layout? Totally or just few views?

If the answer is 2 of 30 or kind of that, make a second viewcontrollews layout with same "custom class"  but different "Story ID" is enough.

Comment: you mean in the same StoryBoard, I should have two Different VC for the same screen? and call them appropriately based on the device?

Comment: it depends, but that's an option.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: No, we do not *need* separate storyboards. The answer to your question of whether you *should* make different storyboards is not so simple.

Basically it is a decision you will make based on your judgement. There is no correct answer. I'd suggest you start with one and if things start getting messy, create a second one. Just don't make the first storyboard too big before you decide if you need to split it out into two or not. It really depends on how different your designs are.